# Can I save the keyboard input in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a code, where pressing a key reproduces a sound generated by the computer, my concern is, how can I store the keys in the order they were pressed in a list and print it?

Here is the code:

```
from array import array 
import pygame 
from pygame.mixer import Sound, get_init,  pre_init

class Note(pygame.mixer.Sound): 

def __init__(self, frequency, volume=.1): 
    self.frequency = frequency 
    Sound.__init__(self, self.build_samples()) 
    self.set_volume(volume) 

def build_samples(self): 
    period = int(round(get_init()[0] / self.frequency)) 
    samples = array("h", [0] * period) 
    amplitude = 2 ** (abs(get_init()[1]) - 1) - 1 
    for time in range(period): 
        if time < period / 2: 
            samples[time] = amplitude 
        else: 
            samples[time] = -amplitude 
    return samples  
pre_init(44100, -16, 1, 1024)
pygame.init() 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 480], 0) 

sounds = {} 
keymap = {pygame.K_p: 880, pygame.K_r: 440} 

while True:
    key_pressed=[]
    evt = pygame.event.wait() 
    if evt.type == pygame.QUIT: 
        break 
    elif evt.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
        if evt.key in keymap: 
            note = Note(keymap[evt.key]) 
            note.play(-1) 
            sounds[evt.key] = note
            key_pressed.append(note)
    elif evt.type == pygame.KEYUP: 
        if evt.key in sounds: 
            sounds.pop(evt.key).stop()
```

Comment: It looks like you've almost got it, except that you reset `key_pressed` back to an empty list at the top of your loop.  Try moving that statement outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem !!!

```
while True:
    key_pressed=[]
```

and here is the solution :

```
key_pressed_list = key_pressed
print(key_pressed_list)
```